# how do I tether my computer and blackberry?

Tags: windows-7, blackberry, tethering

- I have Windows 7 Home Premium
- Blackberry Curve 9300
- 6.0 bundle 1478 (v6.0.0.380, platform 6.6.0.86)
- desktop software 6.0.0.380

I was able to connect with desktop software version 5 but 6 does not work. I am able to connect to the internet just fine with the device itself (ie can browse the web).

How can I debug this?

update: here's the error message:

when i try to connect i get the message "failed to start mobile internet. the specified port is not open. please check your profile settings and make sure your radio is turned on. this service might also have been turned off by your wireless service provider or your administrator"

Comment: Can you expand on "Does not work"?  Like what happens when you try?  What actions *have* you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering my own question

the problem was blackberry desktop manager 6. it just doesn't work. i downgraded to version 5 sp1 and everything worked just fine

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out "[HOWTO: BlackBerry As Modem For Laptop](http://www.blackberryfaq.com/index.php/Using_BlackBerry_As_Modem)" (from the BBFAQ), and try a few things they talk about.